# How to create a named multi dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529865/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Hi guys I need to create an array that can be accessed like this:

```
var cssValue = cssArray[element][property][value];
```

Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: it seems more likely an object than a simple array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather create an object instead of an array

```
var cssObject = {
   element : {
      property : {
         value : "your value"
      }
   }
}
```

since it seems that you may have some non-integer keys in your structure (`property/value` could be strings)

and you get the value with

```
 cssObject["element"]["property"]["value"] 
 // or cssObject.element.property.value
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one simple way to do so:

```
var myarray = new Array(10);
for (i=0; i <10; i++){
myarray[10] = new Array();
}
```